# common variable for log4j.xml configuration

Tags: java, log4j

I have log4j.xml configuration like this:

```
<appender name="MyAppender"class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">   
     <param name="File"     value="/logs/custom/my.log"/>
...  
 </appender>
```

However the root directory of my file are the same for a lot of appender. Is there a way to defined "/logs/custom/" as a variable and reused it in all of my appender.

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**UPDATE**: The original answer applies to Log4j 1.x

Log4j 2.x has much richer support for properties in configuration file, see the Log4j manual about [Configuration with properties](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Configuration_with_Properties).

**Log4j 1.x (the original answer):**

The only way to achieve something similar when you are using `log4j.xml` is to set a system property at startup and then reference that from your `log4j.xml`.

At startup, you set your system property:

```
java -Dlog_dir=/var/logs/custom     com.yourorg.yourapp.Main
```

Or set it programmatically at runtime (before initializing Log4j):

```
System.setProperty("log_dir", "/var/logs/custom")
```

Then you can reference it like this:

```
<appender name="MyAppender"class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">   
     <param name="File" value="${log_dir}/my.log"/>
     ...  
</appender>
```

Or in properties file, like this:

```
log4j.appender.MyAppender.File = ${log_dir}/my.log
```

Source: I got inspiration for this answer from [Using system environment variables in log4j xml configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201188/using-system-environment-variables-in-log4j-xml-configuration).

Also, if you are running under Tomcat, you can use `${catalina.home}` variable, like this:

```
<appender name="MyAppender"class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">   
     <param name="File" value="${catalina.home}/logs/my.log"/>
     ...  
</appender>
```

Comment: what if i  don't want it to pass it with java args. Is there any way where i can initialize in log4j.xml?

Comment: You could always use System.setProperty() to set the property programmatically at runtime, before initializing Log4j.

Answer (score 14):

It is possible in XML as well to define a variable and reuse it in the rest of the doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" [
  <!ENTITY logHome "/logs/folder1/folder2">
]
>
```

Then, refer to this variable just defined, as &logHome;

```
<param name="File" value="&logHome;/folder3/my.log"/>
```

How about that?

(I believe I learnt about XML entity references some time ago at this link: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipentref/index.html)

Comment: is there any way where i define a default param to this variable which gets overrided by system property set outside ..... may using java args?

Comment: No. But you can use a system property with different syntax, see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe this is possible using XML configuration, but it is in a .properties file configuration:

```
mysubdir = /logs/custom
...
log4j.appender.MyAppender.File = ${mysubdir}/my.log
```

Comment: It is possible to use system properties in XML syntax, see the accepted answer. Not possible to define them in XML, though.

Comment: Actually, in Log4j 2.x, it is possible to define them also, in XML. https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Configuration_with_Properties