# log4j.properties to log4j2 log2.xml

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, configuration-files

what is the equivalent log4j.properties file in log4j2.xml to this file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, DEF
log4j.appender.DEF=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.DEF.File=${catalina.home}/webapps/myApp/logs/hasan.log 
log4j.appender.DEF.DatePattern='.'dd-MM-yyyy

# layout-config fro root-logger
log4j.appender.DEF.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.DEF.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} UTC [%25.25t] %-5p %25.25c %x - %m%n
```

Comment: You could have a look at this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414639/converting-log4j-properties-to-log4j-xml?lq=1#15659139. There is an online service to convert the settings. The GitHub repository is also linked on the service page.

Comment: This convertor is for log4j and not log4j2

Comment: This little, but important, difference I have overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your equivalent **log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="DEF" 
                     fileName   ="${sys:catalina.home}/webapps/myApp/logs/hasan.log" 
                     filePattern="${sys:catalina.home}/webapps/myApp/logs/hasan.log.%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss}">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} UTC [%25.25t] %-5p %25.25c %x - %m%n"/>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="true" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO" >
            <AppenderRef ref="DEF" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this log4j2.xml file configuration

```
<Configuration status="warn">
<Properties>
    <Property name="basePath">logs/</Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="fileLogger" fileName="${basePath}/hasan.log"
        filePattern="${basePath}/reporting-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] [%-5level] %c{1}:%L - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                modulate="true" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>

    <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout
            pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] [%-5level] %c{1}:%L - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```